# operator overloading, member and non-member function, which one has priority?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Say I have a `Complex` number class and `operator+` is overloaded twice, both as a member function and as a global function, for example:

```
class Complex {
public:
    Complex operator+(const Complex& c);
};
Complex operator+(const Complex& a, const Complex& b);
```

And in the main function I will call the operator+ like follows:

```
Complex a, b;
Complex c = a + b;
```

Which `operator+` function will be called? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: @KevinDTimm sorry i have modified the post to show what I actually did, and this code can compile fine

Comment: Operator overloading is a well defined process, answered in 1000's of places on the internet (one of which is linked above).  Yours is not a new problem so it would behoove you to use existing resources rather than increasing the noise by asking the same question again.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I don't see where the other question describes which candidate will be selected when there are both member and non-member candidates. Neither can I make sense of the relevant section of the standard, so I'd be interested to see an answer to this question.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I've done some search online actually and didn't find the answer to the exact question I had..

Answer (score 11):

Members are not preferred over non-members in general, nor *vice versa*. C++'s overload resolution rules are applied to select one or the other.

A member function, for the purpose of overload resolution, is considered to have an *implied object parameter* (§13.3.1/2). So

```
Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& c);
```

is treated as though it takes *two* arguments: the original `const Complex& c`, and another `Complex&` which refers to the object used to call the member function (in effect, `*this`).

Suppose we have two `Complex` variables:

```
Complex c1, c2;
```

Both `c1` and `c2` are non-`const`, so in order to call

```
c1.operator+(c2)
```

the parameter `c`, which is a `const` reference, has to bind to the non-`const` argument `c2`.

On the other hand, to call

```
operator+(c1, c2)
```

*both* parameters `a` and `b`, which are `const` references, have to bind to non-`const` objects, `c1` and `c2`.

The member `operator+` is better because `const Complex&, Complex&` is a better match for `c1, c2` than `const Complex&, const Complex&` because it performs less qualification conversion. (§13.3.3.2/3)

If you change the declaration of the member `operator+` to

```
Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& c) const;
```

then the overload will become *ambiguous*, and compilation will fail.

Comment: So there is no priority between the two and either one could be called? thanks for the elaboration, very instructive:)

Comment: @Brian yes, exactly, it depends on more complicated factors, as I elaborated in my answer

Comment: (overload resolution is one of the more complicated aspects of C++)

Comment: I checked with a debugger and it was indeed the member function that had been called, the linker was just as smart as you thought it would be..

Comment: @Brian: *smart* has nothing to do here (or the linker for what matters). There are rules in the definition of the language, and the compiler must abide by those rules.

Comment: Thanks Brain for your informative answer. For other readers, if you declare c1, c2 as const Complex, the same rule apply but this time the non-member function is chosen instead.

Answer (score -4):

A little hint how you could find it out by yourself: Ùse the debugger to see which method is called.